# Differences between CreateToolhelp32Snapshot and PssCaptureSnapshot functions

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, win32-process

There are two functions  defined in WinAPI in order to capture data of target process ,Can someone one explain use cases of these functions?

- [**PssCaptureSnapshot**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457828(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [**CreateToolhelp32Snapshot**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489(v=vs.85).aspx)

when to use each functions?
If we have to check whether the target process is still alive in windows run-time which one is efficiently help us?

Comment: `If we have to check whether the target process is still alive` - you need open process handle and use it in call `WaitForSingleObject[Ex]`, `WaitForMultipleObjects[Ex]`, `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects[Ex]`, etc

Comment: @RbMm What is the most secured way? using EnumProcess and OpenProcess ,is it guarantee the process existence?

Comment: this is depend from how you want determinate process. by short name ? in this case you need `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` + `Process32First`+`Process32Next` + `OpenProcess` with `SYNCHRONIZE` access. but search process by name not reliable way. unclear what process you need. may be exist another way

Comment: for `PssCaptureSnapshot` you need already have handle to the target process. if you want only get when process exit - for what you `PssCaptureSnapshot` at all ?

Comment: @RbMm I am not using short names,Process ID or or just Process Handle.. There can be multiInstances.In the case of multi instances  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457837(v=vs.85).aspx
can be helpful

Comment: if you have `Process Handle` - just wait on it. if you have `Process ID` - open handle first by `OpenProcess` with `SYNCHRONIZE` access. i not understand for what you need snapshot functions here

Comment: To use `PssCaptureSnapshot` you must have a process handle.  If you have a process handle, `PssCaptureSnapshot` is a ridiculously inefficient way of checking whether the process is still running or not.  Therefore, `PssCaptureSnapshot` is of no use to you.

Comment: The `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` function *might* be useful, but you haven't told us what problem you're actually trying to solve, so it is impossible to say for sure.  Please edit your question to clarify your specific situation.  See also: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/187745)

Comment: Say my main program created GUI window(another process/not child),after sometimes I send a signal(sendMessage) to its close button to safely shut down it,In main program I gave it some times to close( main app wait for some seconds),after time elapsed I want to check whether GUI application is actually closed .. What if it's hang up ? I have to decide to whether its to terminate or task kill.

Comment: If win32 TerminateProcess function fails what can we do ? how to check whether  a particular GUI app(spawn process) still exist with hanging state or not ?

Comment: Using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189(v=vs.85).aspx
`GetExitCodeProcess` is just enough? even if it's hanged ?
That's why I thought to take snapshot of all process currently in WinRT and do  querying and search for it.

Comment: `GetExitCodeProcess` not 100% reliable because process can terminated with code `STILL_ACTIVE`

Comment: @RbMm so what is your suggestion for above matter rather than Snapshotting?

Comment: but i say this at first comment - wait on process handle

Comment: @RbMm Assume if Window(Process) App is hangging while we checking ,what will be the behavior of waitingOnSingleObject return value ?

Comment: why not read msdn ? depend on timeout you use can be or `WAIT_TIMEOUT` or `WAIT_OBJECT_X`

Comment: If TerminateProcess doesn't work, something's gone wrong with Windows; typically faulty hardware or a buggy device driver, the only resolution is to reboot the computer.  Waiting on the process handle (with a timeout of zero so the wait returns immediately) will always tell you whether the process is still running or has exited.  If you instead want to tell whether the GUI process is running normally or has hung, you could try IsHungAppWindow.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I tried that pal,yeah Assume we have create process(Launch Application) of Java Application,what if intermediately JVM faced with a issue and due to that launched java program from our main program is not responding even to terminate process.We have no control of that java program,by snapshoting can we have a guarantee of at least it's exist on windows running process query ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.  But if you have a process handle, there is no situation in which it makes sense to use a snapshot to determine whether that process is still running or not.

Answer (score -2):

The Windows API grows in evolution steps Windows version by Windows version..

CreateToolhelp32Snapshot is available for Windows XP. PssCaptureSnapshot is available from Windows 8.1.

So the difference will be exactly in what is documented. PssCaptureSnapshot may have more functionality. And in most cases the old API versions just call the new ones with the new functionality in transforming the flags and structures for the new version.

I can't tell this in detail here, but I assume that there is no great difference, if the functionality of CreateToolhelp32Snapshot is enough for you.

For me the primary decision is: What Windows version are you targeting? Windows 7? Than the answer is simple what to use... ;)

Depending on the flags, both functions give you what you ask for...

Comment: Thank you for the answer .. I am using Win10 SDK.Currently I am using PssCaptureSnapshot function,I haven't profiled anything yet.I just wanted to know their effectiveness for sake of checking process status,whether it's still alive or not

Comment: @Buddhika - you not need use any of this Snapshot function if you need check are process still alive. you need wait on it handle

Comment: @RbMm thnx for the hint. I will consider that.As you mean using snapshot it could have performance hit isn't it ?

Comment: Yes. Using this functions without need isn't wise and effective... What do you want to know? Change your question to give us a more precise answer.

Comment: CreateToolhelp32Snapshot is from Win95, only NT4 shipped without it.